# Understanding _count_vocab method in sklearn.feature_extraction.text's CountVectorizer class

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I'm using the fit_transform method in CountVectorizer and I'm reading through the code to try and understand what it's doing. I'm a bit confused in _count_vocab method in CountVectorizer, specifically under the nested for loop. For raw documents, I have a list of sentences, and fixed_vocab = False.

```
def _count_vocab(self, raw_documents, fixed_vocab):
    """Create sparse feature matrix, and vocabulary where fixed_vocab=False"""
    if fixed_vocab:
        vocabulary = self.vocabulary_
    else:
        # Add a new value when a new vocabulary item is seen
        vocabulary = defaultdict(None)
        vocabulary.default_factory = vocabulary.__len__

    analyze = self.build_analyzer()
    j_indices = _make_int_array()
    indptr = _make_int_array()
    indptr.append(0)
    for doc in raw_documents:
        for feature in analyze(doc):
            try:
                j_indices.append(vocabulary[feature])
            except KeyError:
                # Ignore out-of-vocabulary items for fixed_vocab=True
                continue
        indptr.append(len(j_indices))
    if not fixed_vocab:
        # disable defaultdict behaviour
        vocabulary = dict(vocabulary)
        if not vocabulary:
            raise ValueError("empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only"
                             " contain stop words")

    # some Python/Scipy versions won't accept an array.array:
    if j_indices:
        j_indices = np.frombuffer(j_indices, dtype=np.intc)
    else:
        j_indices = np.array([], dtype=np.int32)
    indptr = np.frombuffer(indptr, dtype=np.intc)
    values = np.ones(len(j_indices))

    X = sp.csr_matrix((values, j_indices, indptr),
                      shape=(len(indptr) - 1, len(vocabulary)),
                      dtype=self.dtype)
    X.sum_duplicates()
    return vocabulary, X
```

Here vocabulary is an empty defaultdict object. Hence j_indices will not append elements since vocabulary is empty so vocabulary[feature] returns an error and the error is ignored, continuing to the next for loop iteration. It will continue to do this for all doc in raw_documents and all feature in the tokens returned by analyze(doc). In the end of this j_indices and indptr are empty array.array objects.

I thought _count_vocab would create its own object of vocabulary and append values when a new vocab word was encountered, but it doesn't look like it.

In this case, should I provide it my own list of vocabulary? Since I don't have one, where can I get a dictionary of words?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `vocabulary[feature]` returns an error and the error is ignored

There's no error since `vocabulary` is a `defaultdict`. What happens is

```
>>> vocabulary = defaultdict(None)
>>> vocabulary.default_factory = vocabulary.__len__
>>> j_indices = []
>>> analyzed = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "foo", "quux"]
>>> for feature in analyzed:
...     j = vocabulary[feature]
...     print("%s %d" % (feature, j))
...     j_indices.append(j)
...     
foo 0
bar 1
baz 2
foo 0
quux 3
```

with the results

```
>>> dict(vocabulary)
{'bar': 1, 'foo': 0, 'baz': 2, 'quux': 3}
>>> j_indices
[0, 1, 2, 0, 3]
```

So this code works correctly. The `KeyError` catching is there for the case `fixed_vocab=True`.

Comment: Thanks for the help - especially the sample code. Now I have a better sense of what deafultdict is doing. I just read up on it some more and realized that it would append new vocabulary items to the dictionary object if it's not found in the dictionary.

Comment: I'm having trouble in understanding this line: vocabulary.default_factory = vocabulary.__len__. I read the documentation on docs.python.org, but I don't understand what __len__ is doing and how this line helps. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @SammyLee: the default factory is the function that gets called when a key is not already in the `defaultdict`. In this case, it calls its own `__len__` implementation, so each unseen key gets a value that is one more than the previous.